# JDK12 HttpClient - how to remove content-length header

Tags: java

Is there any way to remove content-length request header?
Here's the code I use to initialize HttpRequest:

```
HttpRequest get = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .GET()
                .uri(URI.create("https://www.google.com/"))
                .build();
```

Unfortunately the request headers contains "Content-Length: 0" (checked using fiddler)

Comment: Are you sure you're seeing the `Content-Length` header in the `GET` **request** and not in the response?

Comment: Why do you care? As far as I can find, it is not invalid for a `GET` to specify `Content-Length: 0`. It might be redundant, but it's not invalid.

Comment: @Malt I'm pretty sure.

Comment: @Andreas official Java's http client should give us that option

Comment: @IksSki What JDK are you using? Also, Java 12 is no longer supported (for free) since 13 rolled out recently.

Comment: @Malt I'm using OpenJDK 12.0.2